# gnome-control-center pops up on any keyboard hit

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3

I recently experience a very annoying behaviour of my gnome. anytime I hit a key on a keyboard, it starts gnome-control-center making it almost impossible to use my laptop.

The solution I have now is to rename gnome-control-center -> gnome-control-center____0 and when I need it I have to change name back. is there any other solution to block this auto shortcut?

OS    : ArchLinux
Gnome : 41.3 on X11

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue but I don't know how to solve it properly.
I remove laptop-mode-tools. I noticed that it is only when the backlight of the keyboard it off then I press a key that trigger gnome-control-center.
The only thing new in my system was laptop-mode-tools install via AUR.
I guess there is a bug there?